# How to define file type using c1541 -write command (VICE)

Tags: emulation, c64

I'm trying to copy `foo.txt` file to `disk.64` image using `c1541` utility.

I've tried to write:

```
c1541 disk.d64 -write foo.txt foo
```

The file is copied but as `foo.prg`

How can save it using `SEQ` or `USR` types? I've tried:

```
c1541 disk.d64 -write foo.txt foo.seq
```

only to find that the file is copied as `foo.seq.prg`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `c1541 disk.d64 -write foo.txt "foo,s"` for SEQ-files and `c1541 disk.d64 -write foo.txt "foo,u"` for USR-files.

Comment: Isn't it possible to use REL type. I've tried `r` but id didn't work.

Comment: For REL-files, use `,l`, but you also have to specify tarck/sector, since REL-files are different: `c1541 disk.d64 -write foo.txt "foo,l,01,01"`